# PS Script permission issues

Tags: powershell

world !

I'm very new to the scripting world but I'm currently trying to automate a process a work that involves in moving a folder and its contents to the windows directory on C:.

currently, I have this

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Java Config Files*" -Destination "C:\Windows\" -R
```

it's returning with an error message

> Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Java Config Files' is denied.

any thoughts how I can elevate privileges without having to run the script as admin? or if there is a cmdlet that could achieve this?

Comment: Try to run it as Admin

Comment: C:\Windows is a restricted folder, try runinng as Admin as SNR suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by running as admin by adding runAS cmdlet